# Why are some of my values not getting populated by webapi

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a web-api controller.  I built a DTO to hold a Note.

```
public class NoteContainer
{
    public long? NoteId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }

    public NoteContainer(Note note, string type = null)
    {
        NoteId = note.Id;
        NoteText = note.NoteText;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

I have a method in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void EditNote(NoteContainer container)
    {
        //do work here
    }
```

Before the NoteContainer is sent from the client it has all values.  When it gets to the server, type is null!  Should I not use a variable named type?  Why am I losing the value?

Using Postman I'm sending this json:

```
{
    "noteId": 10,
    "type": "person",
    "noteText": "loves broccoli",
}
```

Comment: Show the JSON you are sending. My guess is that it has lowercase "type" not "Type".

Comment: something is breaking in the `ModelBinder`. Are you hand typing the `name` attribute on your form components (eg `<input type='text' name='propertyName' />`)

Comment: Try this:
{
    "NoteId": 10,
    "Type": "person",
    "NoteText": "loves broccoli",
}

Comment: Without seeing your javascript you're using to send this request, it looks like you're creating one object in your js with the 3 properties, and sending it to `EditNote(...)` -- which can't see type since it's not sent as a separate parameter (would `note.Type` work?). Again, speculation, but posting your client code would help.

Comment: The js is sending the exact same values that the postman is sending.  Capitalizing didn't matter either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That needs default constructor I believe. The problem can be that the `Note` class gets instantiated first and is given to `NoteContainer`.

Comment: Adding a default constructor and, magically, all of my values are being set.    I don't think that it's exactly what you said though.  I think it has something to do with the default parameters in the constructor of the NoteContainer